# Views contexual filter based on nid (not from URL)

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module to display taxonomy terms of a node is referencing to. I am not using the default taxonomy field available in views because I want more freedom on manipulating the rendered taxonomy terms.

When I am in the node page I use contextual filters and I provide the default value from the URL. Easy. But...

For listing nodes of a taxonomy term I use views also and I want the same functionality in there.

The only way I can do this is by providing the default value from the nid of every node (row). So how can I get the nid as a contextual filter in such case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module and add Content: Nid as a field and check mark ☑ exclude from display.

Add **Global: View** a field and pass `[%nid]` token/replacement pattern as an argument as contextual filter.

Note: make sure it's arranged above your View field view so you have access to the `[%nid]` replacement pattern/token.

Comment: Nop...doesn't do the trick and what I did is added nid and viewfield in my fields and put the token of nid to the contextual filters as a fixed value. See this [link]http://i.imgur.com/PLE5zRU.png
Maybe is the fixed value the issue?

Comment: @pierostz updated my answer, you should use this other module.

Comment: Well getting closer. I have created a "child" view as described in the module's readme file. I have added this view as a "Global : View" and put it under the nid field. In the Global: View settings I have added [!nid] as a contextual filter (I also tried [nid] as you say) while choosing the correct child view, but I get the full list of my taxonomy terms. It seems like the view isn't using my contextual filter. Also see image [link]http://imgur.com/fc9TtDY

Comment: @pierostz try with `[%nid]`

Comment: @pierostz also, for the view you're adding as a field, make sure the contextual filter is [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7SMOB.jpg)

Comment: and BOOM!!! Thanks No Sssweat got the point now and I have managed it. Ashame I don't got reputation so I can upvote.